# Why does C++ give preference to rvalue reference over const reference while function call?

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, rvalue-reference, pass-by-const-reference, pass-by-rvalue-reference

So I wrote a code in C++ 11

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void print (int &&a)
{
    cout<<"rval ref";
}

void print (const int& a)
{
    cout<<"const ref";
}

int main()
{
    print(9);   
}
```

The output of code was fascinating that it is "rval refernce"
But if I rewrite the code just removing a function defination:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void print (const int& a)
{
    cout<<"const ref";
}

int main()
{
    print(9);   
}
```

I get output as "const ref"

Edit:
There's one more thing here if I rewrite code again as

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void print (int &&a)
{
    cout<<"rval ref";
}

void print (const int&& a)
{
    cout<<"const ref";
}

int main()
{
    print(9);   
}
```

Still its printing "rval ref" , please explain the logic

Can someone explain why C++ give preference to && over const while passing a ravlue as argument ?## Heading ##

Comment: A literal like `9` is an rvalue, so the rvalue reference overload is preferred.

Comment: There's not much more to it than what you see. `9` is an rvalue, so the overload with the rvalue ref parameter has precedence. But const lvalue refs can also bind to rvalues.

Comment: Why wouldn't an *rvalue* reference get priority for rvalues over an *lvalue* reference?

Comment: The pararmeter "9" is not const. So `print (int &&a)` is used, better match than `print (const int& a)`

Comment: why do you think a literal int =9 can be a ref?

Comment: All the details - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution

Comment: @Ripi2 — the integer constant `9` is definitely `const`. Try feeding it to a function that takes `int&`.

Comment: An integer literal is a prvalue - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category which is a rvalue and therefore prefers to bind to an rvalue reference

Comment: @RichardCritten I am kind of beginner so its hard for me to understand the links you sent , can you briefly explain what does they say?

Comment: C++ has types and value categories - I don't think I can explain this in a few words sorry. It's chapter of a book level of explaining.  The intro para from the above link is better than I could ever do.

Comment: The exact quote from the above link is _"__rvalue__: ...When used as a function argument and when two overloads of the function are available, one taking rvalue reference parameter and the other taking lvalue reference to const parameter, an rvalue binds to the rvalue reference overload ..."_

Comment: @RichardCritten thanks for the information, I will surf more on function overloading on internet

Answer (score 1):

Lets see on case by case basis what is happening:

##### Case 1

Here we consider:

```
void print (int &&a)
{
    cout<<"rval ref";
}

void print (const int& a)
{
    cout<<"const ref";
}

int main()
{
    print(9); //chooses print(int&&) version  
}
```

The behavior of this case 1 can be understood from [over.ics.rank](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.ics.rank#3.2) which states:

> **3.2** Standard conversion sequence **`S1` is a better conversion sequence than standard conversion sequence `S2` if**

> `S1` and `S2` are reference bindings ([dcl.init.ref]) and neither refers to an implicit object parameter of a non-static member function declared without a ref-qualifier, and **`S1` binds an rvalue reference to an rvalue and `S2` binds an lvalue reference**.

(emphasis mine)

This means that in your this case 1, the version with `int&&` is preferred over `const int&`.

---

##### Case 2

Here we consider:

```
void print (const int& a)
{
    cout<<"const ref";
}

int main()
{
    print(9);   //chooses the only viable and available option print(const int&)
}
```

Here in case 2, since an *lvalue reference to `const` object* is allowed to bind to an rvalue, the provided `print(const int&)` is viable and is the only one available and hence is selected.

##### Case 3

Here we consider:

```
void print (int &&a)
{
    cout<<"rval ref";
}

void print (const int&& a)
{
    cout<<"const ref";
}

int main()
{
    print(9);   
}
```

Now, this chooses the first version `print(int&&)` because `9` is an `int` prvalue and not a `const int` prvalue. Note also that for a `const int` prvalue, its `const` will be stripped off before any further analysis and so the first version `print(int&&)` will be selected. This is as specified in [expr#6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr#6):

> If a prvalue initially has the type `cv T`, where `T` is a cv-unqualified non-class, non-array type, the **type of the expression is adjusted to `T` prior to any further analysis.**

This means that for class type `const` prvalues the second version of the function `print` with `print(const C&&)` will be selected unlike the built in type `int`  as demonstrated below.

```
struct C 
{
    C()
    {
        std::cout<<"default ctor"<<std::endl;
    }
};
void print (C &&a)
{
    cout<<"rval ref";
}

void print (const C&& a)
{
    cout<<"const ref";
}
const C func()
{
    const C temp;
    return temp;
}
int main()
{
    print(func()); //prints const ref  
}
```

The output of the above program for class type `C` is:

```
default ctor
const ref
```

As is evident from the above example, for **class types** the second version of print with `const C&&` will be selected.

Comment: I think the OP is puzzled why a literal `9` does not bind to a const rvalue reference -- I mean, there is nothing more const than a literal , is there?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica This is because for built in types like `int` the `const int` prvalue is adjusted to `int` meaning its `const` is stripped off.  So even if there was a `const int` prvalue its `const` will be stripped off and hence the first `print` version with `int&&` will be selected. But this stripping off of const doesn't happen for class types and so if we were to pass a class type const prvalue the second version of `print` will be selected. I have added more detailed explanation for this in my answer. Check out my updated answer(case 3 in particular).